# How can we prevent a Liferay admin user(having admin role) to login on public URL

Tags: liferay

We have a public URL - URL1 and a private URL - URL2

We want an admin user,who can login as admin(with admin role) only in private URL2.
If the same user tries to login from public URL1,he should be allowed to login as a non-admin user (without the admin role) i.e he should be blocked to login as an admin user from public URL1.

How can we prevent a Liferay admin user(having admin role) to login on public URL, instead he should be allowed to login as a non-admin user from public URL

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Lifecycle Event](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.1/liferay-workspace/extensions/lifecycle-login-preaction), e.g. a "login-pre-action" (or -post-) as in the documented template. In its implementation, you get access to a LifecycleEvent, which encapsulates the original HTTP request/response. With this you can figure out, who is logging in and from which endpoint they're connecting. Validate this with your conditions, and send appropriate redirects.

Edit: After your comment that this might be a major performance problem:

- First, I only believe that this is a major performance problem, when you have measured it and provide numbers.
- Second, Instead of the linked default's Component's key `login.events.pre`, you're using `key=servlet.service.events.pre`, you might want to try `login.events.post`.
- Third, you might inadvertently have hit the proper implementation. Note that web login might travel with the browser: A session is not bound to a certain IP address. Once logged in from a privileged network, an Administrator might easily hibernate their notebook, bring it to Starbucks next door and open it again. The session (unless it's timed out) would be perfectly valid to allow privileged access from Starbucks Wifi, unless you're checking on every request.

If you're really picky with your performance, you might want to find a non-database mechanism to store a flag that access has been checked already - e.g. store the approved browser's address in the session. Wow, I wouldn't have guessed that I'd propose in public to store something in the session ever.

But in general: A performance issue would be measurable. Reading code can detect performance issues very rarely - or at least not the ones that are worth working on.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help. It helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi Olaf, Using Lifecycle Event has solved my problem .                                        
But there is one issue since we have created this Lifecycle Event and is being called on every request@Component(immediate = true, property = {"key=servlet.service.events.pre"},service = LifecycleAction.class)